# Is it possible to 'refresh' your website with newly added data to a json file?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am currently working on a project when I came across an issue. I have made a code using flask, python and html which allows the user on the website to submit information (comments) to an external 'forum.json' file which is connected to the python script. However, to see the new comment added, I have to manually rerun flask for the script which is bothersome and impossible for someone else than me using the website. Is there any way to automatically load this new data into the website without having to rerun the entire script? If there is a better way to solve this than to save the data in a separate json file I'm all ears.

(The file is large so I'm unable to put it here, but the json file consists of multiple dictionaries in a list, where every time the new comment is sent, a New dictionary is created in the list)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at solving this with a database instead of a json-file.

Answer (score 1):

You can save this data to sqlite very easily and im sure its easier than saving it to a .json file. Heres what I have in my **init** file. This includes the flask app and the database.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
#DB_NAME can be anything as long as it ends in .db
db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = 'db.db'

# this creates the flask app and im sure you have something similar
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'fuwhieasdlvkhjzbuiefnfuialdwoqurpiadsfnxv'
    # this configs the databse and you can copy paste it
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    # .models is where we can setup the database model, this model just has all 
    the info about the data we want
    from .models import Comment
    
    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix="/")
    # create_database is the function I use to create the database
    create_database(app)
     
    return app


def create_database(app):
    # checks to see if there is a databse already created, if not it creates one
    if not path.exists('backendscratch/' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print("created database")
```

Heres an example of the databse model, you can add as many columns as you want the only requirement is a primary id. This is just a .py file.

```
from . import db
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


class Comment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = db.Column(db.String(10000))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=False), default=func.now())
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

Heres how you would add a reply to the database in your views file.

```
@views.route('/b', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def b():
    if request.method == "POST":
        commentdata = request.form.get("id of your html form")

        if len(data) >= 1:
            new_comment = Comment(data=comment)
            db.session.add(new_reply)
            db.session.commit()
        # heres an example of querying all of your comments
        allcomments = db.session.query(Comment)
        # and heres how you would return allcommments to your html file
            return("yoursite.html, comments=allcomments")
```

and heres how you could print all comments, or specific comments in your html with jinja (you dont have to install jinja}}

```
    {{for comment in comments}}
    <ul>
    <li>
    {{comment.data}}
    </li>
    </ul>
{{ endfor}}
```

or for a specific item

```
{{for comment in comments}}
{{if comment.id = 1}}
<p> {{comment.data}} </p>
{{ endfor }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Does this also apply to other things such as a user login and registration system?

Comment: yes it does. please mark my answer as the answer i need that stack overflow repity reputation. also heres a video you can reference if my answer didnt explain things well enough https://youtu.be/dam0GPOAvVI?t=4550